# JavaScript onmouseover For Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to add a hover message on a dropdown menu for each selection using JavaScript?

[image: Dropdown Menu]

Would I use something like `document.getElementById('name_of_html_id')` followed by one of the four options?

How would I traverse through each HTML option where I would use `onmouseover`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a title attribute, e.g.

```
<select id="xMySelect">
    <option title="Hovered aaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
    <option title="Hovered bbbbbbbbbbb">bbbbbbbbbbb</option>
</select>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b7F7T/1/

Or with JS:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("xMySelect");

sel.options[0].setAttribute('title', 'hovered item 1');
sel.options[1].setAttribute('title', 'Second item hovered');
```

Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/b7F7T/3/

Comment: Wow, didn't realize it could be that easy, but unfortunately I cannot edit the HTML since the platform is SaaS. I guess I'll need to use JavaScript to inject titles to each option at run time? I'm not sure how to do this for each option...

Comment: Awesome! You the man!! I never knew the 'options' is an array... interesting.